# Regexp, how to properly use OR when filtering syslog

Tags: regex

This should be pretty simple, however, I am not skilled enough. I need to build a regular expression to evaluate whether an incoming `syslog` contains one of the strings: `MAC_MOVE` or `HOSTFLAPPING`. The first for Catalyst switches and second for Nexus.

This is what I have:

```
*.MAC_MOVE.*|.*HOSTFLAPPING.*
```

but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Could it be because your regexp starts `*.` instead of `.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is just to look for the terms: `(MAC_MOVE)|(HOSTFLAPPING)` [See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/sK5rC7).

Also, watch out, the `*.` will throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

You have unnecessary `.*` in your regex causing OR mechanism to fail.

Use this regex:

```
MAC_MOVE|HOSTFLAPPING
```